# How to implemt the full fledge mailing functionality in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: email

Like out look i need to implement the full fledge mailing functionality in sharepoint site. Is that possible to implement this?
What are the possible  storage location of the email?

Comment: You can hook announcement lists to "Incoming Email" ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx ) and add a event receiver/workflow on any other list for ItemUpdating/ItemUpdating and use SPUtilit7.SendEmail ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460489.aspx ).

Comment: @eirikb I recommend you post this as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook announcement lists to "Incoming Email" ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx ).

For outgoing you can add an event receiver/workflow on any other list for ItemUpdating/ItemUpdated and use SPUtility.SendEmail ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460489.aspx ).